# ant4eclipse classpath problem

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ant4eclipse

i have a problem with my project and ant4eclipse. If i run the build.xml i got this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" : org.ant4eclipse.lib.core.exception.Ant4EclipseException: Exception
whilst resolving the classpath entry '[EclipseClasspathEntry: path: 
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container entryKind: 0 outputLocation: null exported: false]' of project 'MyProject': '

No 'jdtClassPathLibrary' defined for library entry 
'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container'. 
To resolve this problem, please define a 'jdtClassPathLibrary' 
element inside your ant build file:

ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary name="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"  
fileset dir="..."/
/ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary
```

But where can i find the files?
The .classpath file has just this entry:

```
classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there in your `.classpath` is a container entry. That's a sort of shorthand which means "include all the jars which are part of this container". The definition of which jars make up a container is stored in a file called `variablesAndContainers.dat`, in the workspace's `.metadata` directory (these definitions are workspace-wide, not scoped to a particular project).

As far as i know, ant4eclipse can read `.classpath files`, but not the `variablesAndContainers.dat` file (this was certainly true last time i used ant4eclipse, a couple of years ago). That means that although it can find that you have a classpath entry the `org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container` container, it cannot find out what the definition of that container is.

So, whenever you use a container, you have to supply a definition of it to ant4eclipse, in the form of an `ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary` element, exactly as the error message says:

```
<ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary name="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container">
    <fileset dir="..."/>
</ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary>
```

The fileset tag should define the jar files which make up the container.

Comment: You're my hero! The variablesAndContainers.dat contain all missing path to the jar's :-)